# Internal Transaction for CryptoPunks

Tags: transactions, blockchain, etherscan, nft

I am researching NFTs and I would like to understand how transactions are recorded and sales happen. For example the following transaction [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x89a9c8a18d3d4d6b487acdca7919eeabb2678d7363f7a13f5abb0fd7a894c65e) has a contract with 2 internal transctions. This transaction has been recorded as 1.8 ETH on the Opensea for the specific CryptoPunk. However, one of the internal transactions shows that there is 0.045 ETH transafer in this contract which I cannot understand what exactly means. This pattenr is present in many similar transactions for other CryptoPunks. Can someone please help with this? Why there is this second internal transaction, why is needed and what does exactly mean? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The function buy in the smartcontract calls `transferEther`. It executes `transferFeeToBeneficiary` then `beneficiary.transfer(beneficiaryFee)`, it's the 0.045 ETH transfer. Other called function in `transferEther` is `owner.transfer(value)` to owner of the token.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apart from the coding aspect, what does this exactly mean? Is 0.045 a fee the buyer pays for the transaction to the platform? Because this sale is recorded as 1.8 ETH on opensea and larva labs and I can't figure out what is this 0.045 ETH